# Using the SSRS Web Service ReportService2010, how can you set a report option "hide in tile view"?

Tags: c#, web-services, reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I'm using the ReportService2010 web service (e.g. http://[server]/ReportServer_WLTSQL05/ReportService2010.asmx?wsdl) to upload an SSRS report.

In the GUI front end I am able to go to the properties section of a report and select a check box to 'Hide in Tile View' and would like to perform the same action after uploading my report via the web service. How can I do that?

Currently my code looks like:

```
var reportProperty = new Property[0];
reportService.CreateCatalogItem(type, reportObjectName, folderPath, true, reportBytes, reportProperty, out warnings);
```

And I've tried adding different types to the Property array but not achieved success yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just managed to change this via:

```
var property = new Property { Name = "Hidden", Value = "true" };
var properties = new Property[1];
properties[0] = property;
reportService.SetProperties(reportObject.Path,properties);
```

So I went back to the original code and updated it to:

```
var reportProperty = new Property[1];
var hideProperty = new Property { Name = "Hidden", Value = hideFromTileView.ToString() };
reportProperty[0] = hideProperty;
reportService.CreateCatalogItem(type, reportObjectName, folderPath, true, reportBytes, reportProperty, out warnings);
```

And it all works now.